# Cyrillic support in svn's svnlook result

Tags: svn, ubuntu, encoding, character-encoding, svnlook

I've trying to get list of updated/added/deleted files from SVN by svnlook using:

```
/usr/bin/svnlook changed -r 77 /var/lib/svn/epsilon/decorhouse
```

but I got some strange thing:

```
A   data/cms/1315771790_?\208?\147?\209?\128?\208?\176?\209?\132?\209?\132?\208?\184?\209?\130?\208?\190 ?\208?\179?\209?\128?\208?\176?\209?\134?\208?\184?\209?\143 4.jpg
```

I know this filename is Cyrillic and in Windows-1251 encoding. This file is normally saved in SVN itself, so I can commit and update it normally. But how can I get the correct filename from svnlook?

Thanks!

P.S. Ubuntu 11.04 x64

Comment: One addition: I have using svnlook call from PHP, like exec("svnlook ....", &$output);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try invoking following command before running `svnlook`:

```
export LANG="ru_RU.cp1251"
```

You can also set a default lang in your shell start scripts (`.bashrc`, for example), so you won't have to export it every time.